# SalesForce Action Button Not Passing Variables?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, visual-flows, clone

I've created a flow to clone Quote and related Quote Line Items ([using this as a loose guide](https://salesforce-flowsome.com/use-case-clone-any-objects-with-related-lists-with-flow/)).

I'm working in a sandbox environment. When I run 'Debug' in the Flow builder, the flow executes as intended, and a clone is created from the chosen Quote record with related QLIs attached.

My flow is as follows:

[image: flow overview]

***1. Set screen flow to allow user to choose to clone related QLIs***

[image]

***2. Assign variables***

[image]

***3. Clone the Quote with all record values***

[image]

***4. Assign new Quote ID to new variable***

[image]

***5. Update some fields on the new Quote record so name and status are more accurate - Here setNewQuoteName variable is just random text***

[image]

***6. When 'Yes, Clone' is chosen on the screen flow, grab all related QLI records***

[image]

***7. Loop through each related QLI record that was collected***

[image]

***8. Update the values in each related record grabbed***

[image]

***9. Add each related record to a collection***

[image]

[image]

***10. After the last collected QLI has been looped over, create new QLIs related to the newly created quote, using the info stored in the record collection from step #9.***

[image]

***11. Decision - If Use_Variable_for_Cloned_Quote_ID is null or an empty string, return a message that lists values of all variables. Otherwise, return success message with link to new Quote.***

- From the 'Debug' in the flow itself, you can see all variables are being correctly stored and accessed.

[image]

The success message even returns the correct url to the newly created quote, and the sandbox environ will show the newly created quote with all related QLIs accurately.

[image]

[image]

However, running the flow from the action button within the same record used in 'Debug' above, I hit the created error, and the quote and related qlis do not clone:

[image]

[image]

***As you can see, it appears to be an issue with variable access. How can this be fixed?***

Comment: Can you confirm how you are getting the Record id in this screen flow.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala - Yes - I created a variable with data type 'Record' and Object 'Quote', and set the variable name to recordID. Availability Outside the Flow was set to 'Available for input'.  Then, as you can see in the image under '2. Assign variables', I assign recordID > QuoteID to variable Original_Quote_ID.

Comment: recordId is case sensitive. Can you try as `recordId` as variable

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala - I apologize for the mistype above - In the flow, we're directly referencing the variables and values, so case does not seem to be the issue here. This should be visible in the screenshots above.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala - Ah, I see what you mean. I've updated the previously 'recordID' variable to 'recordId', and I am still getting the same result. It seems like we're still not getting the Id when the button triggers the flow from the record.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I've adjusted some additional screenflows I had set pulling other values, and it works now. Thank you! I didn't realize the flow would auto-set the recordId variable, if it's in correct case. If you will please set the comment as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: As mentioned above, if you create a flow action, make sure your flow has a text variable named "recordId" (CASE MATTERS), the starting record Id will be picked up automatically. 
Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_action.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above recordId is case sensitive. Can you try as `recordId` as variable

Comment: Yes - This was exactly the issue - Thanks for the help and for submitting as an answer!